# Deleting multiple data in table inside if statement

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was working on inventory system and I'm supposed to delete items if following statements are met:

1. Item may be deleted if the item doesn't have any transactions yet, like sales and stock transfer. In other words, if item was just recently added but not yet used to any transaction.
2. If item has already been used in sales and other transactions, item is not allowed to be deleted (opposite of #1).

The following are my codes and I'm having a trouble in my second statement. It doesn't say anything, it just reloads the page, but the first statement works.

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['deleteUser'])) {
        $code = $_POST['code'];

        $result = mysqli_query($link,
            "SELECT stocktransferdetail.*, salesdetails.* FROM stocktransferdetail 
            INNER JOIN salesdetails ON stocktransferdetail.itemCode = salesdetails.itemCode 
            WHERE stocktransferdetail.itemCode LIKE '$code'");

        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $item = $row['itemCode'];

            if ($code == $item) {
                print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
                print 'alert("Deleting selected item is not allowed.")'; 
                print '</script>';
            }

            if ($code !== $item) {  
                mysqli_query($link,
                    "DELETE FROM itemmaster, itemunitprice, inventory 
                    INNER JOIN itemmaster ON inventory.itemCode = itemmaster.itemCode
                    INNER JOIN itemunitprice ON inventory.itemCode = itemunitprice.itemCode
                    WHERE itemCode = '$code'");
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Could you add ON CASCADE DELETE to your database tables and just use "DELETE FROM itemmaster WHERE itemCode = '$code'"? Sometimes using a simpler SQL statement can help avoid running into tricky little issues.

Comment: You could do this in a single SQL query instead of having to use PHP for logic. Am I correct in assuming the salesdata table will always have the stocktransferdetail data? If not, your query should not be using an `INNER JOIN` but a `LEFT JOIN` instead.

Comment: Try a `while` instead of an `if` - `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ))`

Comment: Plus, are you getting any errors? Are you checking for them? If not, add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` see if it yields anything,  as well as `or die(mysqli_error())` to `mysqli_query()`

Comment: i tried 'while' and replace the IF and the script is kept on showing

Comment: I also tried to replace my delete statement guys, im sorry i forgot to tell and i tried to echo something like, "HELLO" to the 2nd if/else and nothing happens.

Comment: Btw, it's bad idea to do something similar to `LIKE '$code'` or `itemCode = '$code'`. Because someone could pass something similar to `code=' OR 2>1 --` to your script, which will evaluate into query `DELETE ... WHERE itemCode = '' OR 2>1` that will wipe the hell out of your tables.

Comment: I got worried. @.@ Thank you Mr. Modchan im gunna say this to my partner and we will work on that. Anyways, the same thing happens, the first statement is working and the second do nothing. :(

Comment: If your first works using `WHERE stocktransferdetail.itemCode LIKE '$code'");` why are you using `WHERE itemCode = '$code'");` in your second? Did you try using the same thing as your first query?

Comment: No Mr. Fred-ii I mean, This statement if ($code == $item) {..(script) is here..}
is working and  if ($code !== $item) {   } do nothing but reloads the page. :(

Comment: i also use ELSE instead of another IF but nothing. :(
i guess there's nothing  wrong with the query because it works to the other php

Comment: @Katolich, take a look at code example for [`mysqli_prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) function to get some idea of parametrized SQL queries (which are correct way to do what you are trying to do). This won't help you solve your problem though.

Comment: I'll be back :) Thank you guys.

Comment: echo $item and also echo $row['itemCode'] then kill the script. What do they contain? Why are you using the equals to operator in one condition but the identical in the next? Is there reasoning behind this? Identical operator can mess you up if you don't know what you're doing.

Comment: Hi guys! i found it out already :)